# Looking for a note taking and organization application

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a OneNote lookalike, but I'm especially interested in one feature of OneNote, that is the capability of doing OCR on the fly, taking screen-shots, and and indexing them for text search. Is there anything under Linux (possibly free) that does the same?

Comment: You could use Evernote or Notion in the browser if this would not be an issue for you.

Comment: See https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-onenote/ for software recommendations.